# subprocess not receiving output

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I would like to serialize a dataframe to pipe it to an executable that at the moment for testing purposes just prints out whatever it is receiving from the command line.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    
import subprocess

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size = 1000).reshape(100,10))
    
exe =  r"C:\Users\Snake91\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe "

process = subprocess.Popen([exe],
                           stdin =  subprocess.PIPE,
                      stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate(np.array(df).tobytes())
```

Below the code of the executable

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int size = sizeof(argv)/sizeof(argv[0]) + 1;
    if (size > 1)
    {
        for (int idx = 1; idx < size; idx++)
        {
            std::cout << argv[idx];
        }
    }
}
```

When running the python script, however, I get an empty byte string instead of the serialized dataframe. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Doesn't `argv` receive CLI parameters ? While passing them in `communicate` may send them to `std::cin` ?

Comment: Add another `std::cout` that always outputs something and you will probably see that Python will receive that output. It is the C++ program that is not reading the input - as mentioned above, the argument to `communicate` gets sent to the process's standard input so you need to read that with something like `std::cin`. `argv` contains command line arguments, so if your command was `[exe, "arg1"]`, your subprocess would print `arg1`. Also, `argc` contains the number of arguments passed to the program (+1 because #0 is the path to the executable), so you don't need the `sizeof` magic.

Comment: @azro I've tried literally for hours... thanks!

Comment: @Czaporka thank you as well, actually using `[exe, "arg1"]` I got a UnicodeError that I couldn't in any way address, that's why I switched to `communicate`. I had no clue actually *where* `communicate` was passing the arguments. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed out in the comments, `communicate` does **not** pass the arguments to the command line, but through `std::cin`. The code of the executable has to be modified in the following way to make it work.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string line;
    while (getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help.